# group Timeseries by hourly count in python pandas

Tags: python, data-analysis, data-manipulation

```
df['data'] = df['data'].dropna()
df['data'] = df['data'].str.strip("'(), ")
df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
df['data'] = df['data'].dropna()
```

This is my data set header

```
0   2019-05-26 00:00:00.326000+00:00
1   2019-05-26 00:00:00.690000+00:00
2   2019-05-26 00:00:02.850000+00:00
3   2019-05-26 00:00:02.971000+00:00
4   2019-05-26 00:00:03.432000+00:00
Name: data, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

I need to count hourly basis. 
required output

---

### time interval  :  Total

0 - 1 : 5 times
1 - 2 : 10 times
..
..
23 - 24: 4 times

---

df[data].head()

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.Series.dt.hour`.

Given `df`:

```
                     data
0 2019-05-26 01:00:00.326
1 2019-05-26 02:00:00.690
2 2019-05-26 02:00:02.850
3 2019-05-26 03:00:02.971
4 2019-05-26 05:00:03.432
```

Using `df['data'].dt.hour` with `pd.DataFrame.groupby.count`:

```
import pandas as pd

df.groupby(df['data'].dt.hour).count()
```

Output:

```
      data
data      
1        1
2        2
3        1
5        1
```